# Mongodb counting the number records where column present after grouping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of records that look like this:

```
{'customer':'unique_value',
 'Date trial':'12/1/2013',
 'Date success':'12/3/2013'}
```

The Date success field is not present in every record, only the records where there was a success have a success field. Each unique customer may have dozens or hundreds of trials. I'd like to get a list of the customers, the number of trials, and the number of successes

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$group:{_id:'$account',attempts:{$sum:1} }} ]);
```

Will give me the number of trials for each customer, but I'm not coming up with a way to also get the number of records for that customer where the Date success field was present.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

You can use some conditional operators to evaluate the fields. Here is the usage combining [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) with [$ifNull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: { _id: "$account",
        trial:   {$sum: {$cond: [ {$ifNull: ["$trial",0]}, 1, 0]}},
        success: {$sum: {$cond: [ {$ifNull: ["$success",0]}, 1, 0]}}
    }}
])
```

Let's break that down, even if brief it's still a mouthful.

So when we test a field with [**$ifNull**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) ( ["$trial",0] ), it's basically saying that if the field does **not** exist then return a `0` which will be interpreted as `false`. The `field` value will of course be logically `true`.

Then we ask of [**$cond**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) (which is kind of a *ternary*), given this condition (which will be a *result*: true or false) then return either the *true* or *false* value, being the extra arguments.

Finally in the [**$group**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) we implement the [**$sum**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator on the field. And since [**$cond**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) gave us a `1` where there was a `true` condition, or a `0` in the `false` case, then we can consider the **sum** the result of the matching conditions where the *element* was in place as you expected for your query.

Same principle goes for [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). You are shaping your output document to have **both** fields whether they are present or not in the source. The value being assigned to the field depends on whether it **exists** or not. In this case 0 where it's not there and 1 where it is. Then just sum the results.

Comment: I had to read the docs pretty carefully to take apart your answer and figure out how it works. So the $ifNull is going to check if $trial is present and will return either a zero or the value of that column. The value returned with either be zero or not zero which $cond will evaluate as true or false and thus return a 1 or a zero. And then $sum adds it up. Am I getting it? Brilliant solution, thanks.

Comment: @KevinThompson That was pretty much it. Was I coming off a little too glib? Probably should have explained that better but have done a few of these. Glad you got it.

Comment: @KevinThompson I think I may have been a bit short. Hope the edit is more palatable. Your up-vote is always appreciated ;). As said, it was a good question, people often miss this concept.

Comment: I don't think you were short or glib. I appreciate the help.